# where is current directory when Ubuntu 16.04 automatically starts an application at power up

Tags: boot, 16.04, startup, startup-applications, preferences

When I set up my program with Ubuntu > System menu > Preferences > Personal > Startup Applications, and then cycle power on the Linux SBC, when my application starts, which directory does it start in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first directory would be your default directory (`~userid`).  Unless you changed it from the default it would be `/home/yourid`.

Some applications might change the current work directory as part of its configuration.  So if you see an occasion to be in a different folder, it would be, because of the operation of the particular app.

You can actually write a simple script/application to test this.

**The  script:**

myscript.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

date >> /tmp/test.out
echo "Current Workdirectory: $(pwd)" >> /tmp/test.out
```

Create a desktop launcher and place it in your `~/.config/autostart` folder:

**The desktop launcher:**

myapp.desktop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open                                                                                                  
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My Test App
GenericName=Test Application
Comment=A quick test script
Exec=/usr/local/bin/test.sh
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/icons/local/apollo.png
Categories=test;script
StartupNotify=false
```

Save the test.sh file at /usr/local/bin.  Make sure it is executable with `chmod +x test.sh`.

It will automatically run.  You can then view the current directory by examining the redirected `/tmp/test.out` content.  It'll contain the date it was last run, plus your current work directory.

**Tested Output:**

```
$ cat /tmp/test.out 
Wed May 24 16:53:28 EDT 2017
Current Workdirectory: /home/apollo
```